# Why there is very large difference between cross validation scores?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data, cross-validation, score

I have a very simple regression model and I am doing the cross validation. When cv=10 the highest score i got is 60.3 and lowest is -9.7 which is useless.
Average will be 30.

No of row data set= 658

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by cross-validation scores ?

Comment: I think you can try to shuffle the data before training. Maybe the data are clustered together and then training are biased on each fold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [$R^2$ scores](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score) indicate that a linear model does not describe your data well. On top of this, there seems to be a large variability in data. You could try the following:

- If the linear model is supposed to describe the data, check for outliers. They might be responsible for the large variation across the CV folds.
- Try reducing the number of features if there are many. The model might be fitting noise.
- Introducing regularization (lasso or ridge regression) might make the model more robust. This should decrease the variability of the CV errors, but the $R^2$ scores will get even worse.